# "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

I have this SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deputy`.`Votings` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VRSetId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `LNSetIdOfMeeting` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `VRSetIdOfMeeting` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `meetingId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `VRSetId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Votings_VotingRulesSets1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`VRSetId`)
    REFERENCES `deputy`.`VRSets` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Votings_Meetings1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`LNSetIdOfMeeting` , `VRSetIdOfMeeting` , `meetingId`)
    REFERENCES `deputy`.`Meetings` (`LNSetId` , `VRSetId` , `id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

There is primary key made of two fields: "id" and "VRSetId"; "VRSetId" is being also foreign key as there is "VRSets" table with identifying 1-to-1 relationship to "Votings". There is also second foreign key to "Meetings" table which itself have primary key created with two foreign keys in addition to "id" field... "Meetings" table has one-to-many relationship with "Votings" so "Votings" ended up with so many keys... which is fine as I'm using them to get to my data in many different ways. The problem is that since I've added auto-incremenent to all "id" fields - I'm getting such error:

```
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `deputy`.`Votings` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

There is this "Meetings" table with similarly formatted keys and it's working fine:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deputy`.`Meetings` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LNSetId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `VRSetId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `LNSetIdOfCSet` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `CSetId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `LNSetId`, `VRSetId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Meetings_LegalNumbersSets1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`LNSetId`)
    REFERENCES `deputy`.`LNSets` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Meetings_VotingRulesSets1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`VRSetId`)
    REFERENCES `deputy`.`VRSets` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Meetings_ConfigurationSets1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`LNSetIdOfCSet` , `CSetId`)
    REFERENCES `deputy`.`CSets` (`LNSetId` , `id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And the last table related to "Votings" (I've removed data fields in all tables to make it look more clear):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deputy`.`VRSets` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The database was working fine before some minor changes I've made and now I'm not sure what's going on... whole thing was auto-generated by MySQL Workbench and I'm running the script onto MariaDB.

Comment: Could you add the `CREATE TABLE` syntax of the tables you're referencing? Does the code work, if you only use *one* of the foreign key contraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The referenced column needs an index. Your primary key on the `meetings` table is

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `LNSetId`, `VRSetId`)
```

but you're referencing like this in the `votings` table:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`LNSetIdOfMeeting` , `VRSetIdOfMeeting` , `meetingId`)
REFERENCES `deputy`.`Meetings` (`LNSetId` , `VRSetId` , `id`)
```

The order of the columns in an index matters, therefore change it to

```
FOREIGN KEY (`meetingId`, `LNSetIdOfMeeting` , `VRSetIdOfMeeting`)
REFERENCES `deputy`.`Meetings` (`id`, `LNSetId` , `VRSetId`)
```

and it will work.

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f602)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. The order was changed automatically when I was bringing "id" columns to the top in order to get AI attribute to work.